# Deleting Array ( [0] => from print_r output

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a script that will divide mysql results into three columns. Everything worked right but I'm getting my results in this way when **I use print_r code:**

```
Array ( [0] => Seat Siroku [title] => Seat Siroku )
Array ( [0] => Hyundai X35 [title] => Hyundai X35 )
```

**And I should be getting them like this:**

```
Seat Siroku
Hyundai X35
```

**This is my PHP code:**

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT title FROM cars");

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}            

$lists = array_chunk($rows, ceil(count($rows) / 3));

foreach ($lists as $column) {
    echo "<div class='column'>";
    echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($column as $title) {                      
            echo '<li>';
            print_r($title);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

I tried looking everywhere how can I remove this Array strings and I found an answer that print_r is causing it. When I try setting `echo $title` all I get is a Array to String conversation error. So how can I keep just the title as a result? Can someone help me with it? All the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the `title` column in each lowest level array:

```
$lists = array_chunk($rows, ceil(count($rows) / 3));

foreach ($lists as $column) {
    echo "<div class='column'>";
    echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($column as $arr) {                      
            echo '<li>';
            echo $arr["title"];
            echo '</li>';
        }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Remember that each `$arr` corresponds to one record from your result set.  The confusion here might be coming from that you only selected a single column.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks so much! Thanks for the explanation tho also!